# What is the advantage of partitioning a delta / spark table by year / month / day, rather than just date?

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

In many data lakes I see that data is partitioned by year, then month, then day, for example:

```
year=2019 / month=05 / day=15
```

What is the advantage of doing this vs. simply partitioning by date? e.g.:

```
date=20190515
```

The only advantage I can think of is if, for example, analysts want to query all data for a particular month/year. If just partitioning on date, then they would have to write a query with a calculation on the partition key, such as below psuedocode:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LEFT(date,4) = 2019
```

Would spark still be able to do partition pruning for queries like the above?
Are there any other advantages I haven't considered to the more nested partition structure?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would argue it's a disadvantage! Because splitting the date parts makes it much harder to do date filtering. For example say you want to query the last 10 days of data which may cross month boundaries? With a single date value you can just run simple queries like

`...where date >= current_date() - interval 10 days`

and Spark will figure out the right partitions for you. Spark can also handle other date functions, like `year(date) = 2019` or `month(date) = 2` and again it will properly do the partition pruning for you.

I always encourage using a single date column for partitioning. Let Spark do the work.

Also, an important thing to keep in mind is that date format should be `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Also, there's an upper bound on number of partitions in the metastore. One per day will cause problems after more than a decade of historical + future data

Comment: That and other issues is what Delta Lake (https://delta.io) helps address through scalable metadata handling. Same answer applies though, no reason to split dates into separate columns which ends up hurting usability of the data.

Comment: thanks Silvio!
Would Spark still be able to do partition pruning when filtering on the year? e.g.: 
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LEFT(date,4) = 2019

Comment: See my example above, you should just use the `year(date) = 2019` function instead, but the column needs to be an actual date value (e.g. `2019-01-20`)